# Advanced camera settings on Nexus 5

Tags: settings, camera, nexus-5

I have a nexus 5, with android 4.4.4. How can i change advanced camera settings? (iso, shutter speed etc...)

Answer (score 2):

The stock camera app doesn't allow such manual adjustments, so you'll probably need a 3rd-party app such as [DSLR Camera Pro $3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.vipek.camera&hl=en), [Shot Control $3 with a free demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.starvingmind.android.shotcontrol&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) or [Camera FV-5 $5 with a free demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.pro). This will let you manually adjust the shutter speed, aperture, ISO, etc like a DSLR.

Comment: I agree. I used both [DSLR Camera Pro $3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.vipek.camera&hl=en) and [Camera FV-5 $5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.pro), and can recommend them.

Answer (score -1):

you can adjust ISO by going to setting, then advance, and then enabling the manual option. In the camera screen you can click on the +/- icon. -2 is ISO 800 and 0 is ISO 100.

Cheers!

Comment: Which camera app do you refer to here?